# Can a single table inheritance entity extend a class table inheritance entity?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-2.3, single-table-inheritance, class-table-inheritance

This is my base/parent entity, setup so its children are using their own tables.

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="layer_object")
 * @ORM\InheritanceType("JOINED")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="discr", type="string")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorMap({"service"="Service", "aircraft"="Aircraft", ...})
 */
class LayerObject {}
```

Aircraft entity. A simple child that is doing well

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="aircraft")
 */
class Aircraft extends LayerObject
```

Service entity. A complex child, that itself is using single table inheritance.

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="service")
 * @ORM\InheritanceType("SINGLE_TABLE")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="discr", type="string")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorMap({"ground"="Ground", "onboard"="Onboard"})
 */
class Service extends LayerObject {}
```

A child of the Service entity

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Ground extends Service {}
```

`app/console doctrine:schema:validate` finds no errors but `app/console doctrine:schema:update --force` just **won't generate the 'service' table, the one that should use single table inheritance**. Seems like the service entity definition is simply ignored.

Sure I could create the SQL for this table by hand, but the application will grow and at some point I will need to use migrations.

Could anyone point me in some direction? Thanks.

Found a duplicate, but there are no answers so far, see: [Doctrine 2 multiple level inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16489483/doctrine-2-multiple-level-inheritance)

**Edit:**
When I use class table inheritance for the 2nd level too (`@ORM\InheritanceType("JOINED")` for the `Service` entity) it works pretty well. See: [Doctrine2 Multiple level inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11397255/doctrine2-multiple-level-inheritance)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you're trying to achieve is not possible with pure mapping.

The documentation for [Class Table Inheritance](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#class-table-inheritance) and [Single Table Inheritance](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#single-table-inheritance) clearly state:

> The @InheritanceType, @DiscriminatorColumn and @DiscriminatorMap must
>   be specified on the **topmost** class that is part of the mapped entity
>   hierarchy.

You might be able to make this work by implementing a [subscriber](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/event_listeners_subscribers.html#configuring-the-listener-subscriber) to the `loadClassMetaData` [event](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/events.html#lifecycle-events) that changes the inheritance-type dynamically (i.e. based on annotations on of the child entities).

Some further inspiration can be found in [this article](https://medium.com/@jasperkuperus/defining-discriminator-maps-at-child-level-in-doctrine-2-1cd2ded95ffb).

Comment: Thanks a lot. This basically means: 'Choose your inheritance type once at the topmost class and stick with it'. For now this is fine for my application...